# identityhashcode () of the variable changed java

Tags: java

Why does System.identityHashCode() return different int for the same variable ?

```
  public class java {
      public static void main(String[] args) { 
   1-         int v=60000;
   2-         System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(v));
   3-         System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(v));
    
      }
    }
output : 1831932724
         1747585824
```

Comment: Could you try to replace int v = 60000; with Integer v = 60000;? 
what is the line you want me to change?
@turing85

Comment: Please check my answer. It gives a full explanation and demos that show the behaviour. This comment will self-destruct shortly.

Comment: Hey, System.identityHashCode(Object) return the same hash code for an object which is true when you are passing some object but in your case, you are passing a primitive parameter that is being autoboxed to its Wrapper class (everything generating a new autoboxed wrapper object). Therefore if you need to use this method then I would recommend you to use the Wrapper class instead of primitive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When we take a look at the signature of [`System::identityHashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode(java.lang.Object)), we see that it takes an `Object` as parameter. The code provided, however, passes a primitive (`int`) as parameter. The `int` is [autoboxed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) into the corresponding wrapper-class (in the given case: [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html)). Java does cache `Integer`s in a certain range by default, but `60_000` is out of the default-range. This means that the code can be rewritten to:

```
class Ideone {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int v = 60_000;
    final Integer tmp1 = v;
    final Integer tmp2 = v;
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(tmp1));
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(tmp2));
    System.out.println(tmp1 == tmp2);
  }
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/EXv1YS)

Notice that this code is, for our discussion, identical with the code provided, but now we see that the code actually uses two instances of `Integer`. The behaviour is expected since `System:identityHashCode` uses `Object:hashCode`, and `Object:hashCode` will (almost always) return a unique id for each instance.

If we change the code to use only one `Integer` instance, the code works as expected:

```
class Ideone {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Integer tmp1 = 60_000;
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(tmp1));
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(tmp1));
    System.out.println(tmp1 == tmp1);
  }
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/eZCtHW)

Comment: Is that mean when i write   public class java {
      public static void main(String[] args) { 
            int v=60000;
            System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(v));
            System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(v));
    
      }
    }
the output is :1831932724
                      1747585824
because identityHashCode() create two objects . one is created in the line number 2 and one is created in the line number 3  ?
@Turing85

Comment: Method `System:identityHashCode` does not create the objects, the objects are created by the autoboxing mechanism.

Comment: Okay is that mean by autoboxing mechanism two objects are created . one is created in the line number 2 and one is created in the line number 3 ? @Turing85

Comment: not sure which lines you mean by line 2 and 3. By my counting, they are the lines defining static method `main` and the local variable `v`. But they are created by the two lines declaring `tmp1` and `tmp2` (in my code) and by the two calls to `System.identityHashCode(...)` (implicitly, in your code).

Comment: I edited my post and added number to lines can you see the post again and answer my me (in my code  Okay is that mean by autoboxing mechanism two objects are created . one is created in the line number 2 and one is created in the line number 3 ? and in your code the two objects are created in the line of declaration tmp1and the line of declaration tmp2 , right ?) and I am sorry for bothering you @Turing85

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: in this sentence  " Java does cache `Integer`s in a certain range by default "
 when you said the word ( `Integer`s ) you meant the wrapper-class not the primitive datatype ( in another words Java does not cache `int`s ( the primitive datatype ) in a certain range by default ) , right ? @Turing85

Comment: Yes, I meant `Integer`s, not `int`s.